# Python how to split a string into words that contain words with a single quote?

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a string `a`, I would like to return a list `b`, which contain words in a that not starts from `@` or `#`, and not contains any non-word characters.

However, I'm in trouble of keep words like "They're" as a single word. Please notice that words like "Okay....so" should be split into two words "okay" and "so".

I think problem could be solved by just revising the regular expression. Thanks!

```
a = "@luke5sos are you awake now?!!! me #hashtag time! is@ over, now okay....so they're rich....and hopefully available?"
a = a.split()
b = []
for word in a:
    if word != "" and word[0] != "@" and word[0] != "#":
        for item in re.split(r'\W+\'\W|\W+', word):
            if item != "":
                b.append(item)
            else:
                continue
    else:
        continue
print b
```

Comment: What would be the expected result from this?

Comment: ['are', 'you', 'awake', 'now', 'me', 'time', 'is', 'over', 'now', 'okay', 'so', "they're", 'rich', 'and', 'hopefully', 'available']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to combine all these rules into one regex:

```
import re
a = "@luke5sos are you awake now?!!! me #hashtag time! is@ over, now okay....so they're rich....and hopefully available?"
b = re.findall(r"(?<![@#])\b\w+(?:'\w+)?", a)
print(b)
```

Result:

```
['are', 'you', 'awake', 'now', 'me', 'time', 'is', 'over', 'now', 'okay', 'so', "they're", 'rich', 'and', 'hopefully', 'available']
```

The regex works like this:

1. Checks to make sure that it's not coming right after `#` or `@`, using `(?<![@#])`.
2. Checks that it's at the begining of a word using `\b`. This is important so that the `@`/`#` check doesn't just skip one character and go on.
3. Matches a sequence of one or more "word" type characters with `\w+`.
4. Optionally matches an apostrophe and some more word type characters with `(?:'\w)?`.

Note that the fourth step is written that way so that `they're` will count as one word, but only `this`, `that`, and `these` from `this, 'that', these` will match.

Answer (score 0):

The following code (a) treats `....` as a word separator, (b) removes trailing non-word characters, such as question marks and exclamation points, and (c) rejects any words that start with `#` or `@` or otherwise contain non-alpha characters:

```
a = "@luke5sos are you awake now?!!! me #hashtag time! is@ over, now okay....so they're rich....and hopefully available?"
a = a.replace('....', ' ')
a = re.sub('[?!@#$%^&]+( |$)', ' ', a)
result = [w for w in a.split() if w[0] not in '@#' and w.replace("'",'').isalpha()]
print result
```

This produces the desired result:

```
['are', 'you', 'awake', 'now', 'me', 'time', 'is', 'now', 'okay', 'so', "they're", 'rich', 'and', 'hopefully', 'available']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
v = re.findall(r'(?:\s|^)([\w\']+)\b', a)
```

*Gives:*

```
['are', 'you', 'awake', 'now', 'me', 'time', 'is', 'over', 'now', 
 'okay', 'so', "they're", 'rich', 'and', 'hopefully', 'available']
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you don't want words with digits in them and you want to disregard all the other special characters except the *single quote*. You could try something like this:

```
 import re
 a = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z']+', ' ', a)
 b = a.split()
```

I haven't been able to try the syntax, but hopefully it should work. What I suggest is replace every character that is not aplha-numberic or a *single qoute* with a single space. So this would result in a string where your required strings separated by multiple white spaces. Simply calling the `split` function with no argument, splits the string into words taking care of multiple whitespaces as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: The string `'[^0-9a-zA-Z']+'` has unbalanced quotes.  Did you mean  `"[^0-9a-zA-Z']+"`?

Comment: I mean the `regex` should include the set `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `'`. However, I have assumed here that the *single quote* occurs between words only in cases like `I've` or `they're`.

Comment: `[0-9a-zA-Z]` fails on most strings. Eg: `re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ', "لوحة لمفاتيح لعربية")` The other solutions tokenizes that string correctly.